# Onclick event on a link (<a>)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, onclick, anchor

I want to dynamically add links to my pages something like this:

```
foreach (Node node in this._nodes)
    <a target="main" href="MyLink" class="menuclass">node.title</a>
```

But now i want to add c# events to the click of one of this links the event is the same for all the links, how do i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create Server side `Hyperlink` object and register for click event.

Comment: Is this ASP.net webforms, or MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User LinkButton to make the link look like a Hyperlink but behave  like a button.Here is your answer

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (Node node in this._nodes)
{
    LinkButton lnkPost = new LinkButton();
    lnkPost.ID = "lnk" + i.ToString();
    lnkPost.Text = node.Title;
    lnkPost.Click += new EventHandler(LinkPost_OnClick);

    parent.Controls.Add(lnkPost);
}

protected void LinkPost_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add your handler code here
}
```

Comment: Why would you use LinkButton instead of hyperlink when the later is specifically made to suit links?

Comment: hyperlinks will not trigger server side events, it just redirect to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly something like this:

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (Node node in this._nodes)
{
 HyperLink DynLink = new HyperLink();         
 DynLink.ID = "DynLink" + counter.ToString();         
 DynLink.Text = node.title;            
 DynLink.NavigateUrl = "MyLink";  
 counter++;
}
```